# How to display installed apps without using ListView/RecyclerView/CardView etc in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kiosk

I have an application that lists in a `RecyclerView` all apps installed in the Android device.

I would like to select them, and then press a button to open a new activity that will show all the apps I have selected.

But I do not want another listview/recycle view, I want then to be displayed just like they are in the home screen: the icon with the name under it, side by side, etc… Just like it is in any android device. And they should be able to be open as well.

I really have no idea how to display them in this way in the new activity. I am using java.

To resume, I am trying to develop a kind of Kiosk app, where access to the apps could be controlled.

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by not using recyclerview?! you want to show a list and it is made for it. maybe you're looking for a way to show them in a grid. you can use `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Hello @MohammadOmidvar, thanks for you sugestion. Actually, I wanted to display the apps just like they are in home screen, for example. I don't know if they are in a gridview. Do you know?

Comment: i think u need to create custom home screen ?

Comment: Thanks @MohammadOmidvar, GridLayout was all I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to display all the applications in a grid manner just like android default home page, 
You can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager as following code do

```
val numberCol=4

val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,numberCol)

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager)

adapter = ViewAdapter(mlist)

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

- you can launch the corresponding app on item click. 
  I hope it will help you!